# Different sound to play while receiving notifications in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to play some other sound like an alert one on receiving a notification.Is it possible yet as it is the most basic functionality?Below is my code:

```
    const receipts = expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync([ { to: userObj.pushToken, 
sound: 'default', body: notification, data: { withSome: notification }, priority: 'high' } ]);
```

Comment: guys!Please help out.

Answer (score 2):

Expo push server does not support custom sounds. It will swallow whatever you place in the sound field and replace it with default. Attempting to work around their module using the expo service from curl will give you an actual error.

However, custom sounds are possible in expo clients when using your own APNS module server side if the sound is bundled within the .ipa upon delivery to App Store.